# How to create an interactive map in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I've created a page that shows a map of my complex.  The idea is to put icons on the map representing where computers are located, and the user will be able to click on the icon to remote into the machine.

But I also want the icons to be moveable.  Everyone should be able to open the page and drag the computer icon around.  Is this possible using only ASP.NET?

Comment: Anything is "possible". What have you tried to make this idea reality? For the record, ASP.NET is a server side language only. You'll need some HTML, CSS and Javascript to make it all a reality.

Answer (score 1):

you can use following options but not limited :)

1. [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/overlays#Tile_Overlays)
2. [Bing Maps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427610.aspx)
   [bing map sdk](http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the html `<map>` and `<area>` tags along with an image of your complex to create a map that has points on it.

You can see an example of this [here](http://html.cita.illinois.edu/text/map/map-example.php), however this is probably overkill for your requirements. All you need to do is set the `coord` and `shape` attributes for each area, this will give you an element that would represent the computers.

I'm not sure if you can manipulate these in javascript or jQuery though, as I have never tried, but hopefully this will give you a starting point.